# identify each label .innerhtml

Tags: jquery, html

I have severals labels without id, like this:

`<label class="optional" for="Name">Nombre</label>`

I need something like this:

```
h=0;

$('label').each(function(index) {
  $(this).append('id=etiqueta'+h);
  h=h+1;
});
```

But not in the text field.

The result must be this:

```
<label class="optional" for="Name" id="etiqueta0">Nombre</label>
```

Thank you very much,

Greetings,

Álvaro

Comment: What is your usecase for this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to count each iteration of the loop, you can just use the `index` argument. The [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method is used to set the value of an attribute:

```
$('label').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'etiqueta' + index);
});
```

The `append` method which you are currently using is used to append HTML (or text) to an element. It won't affect the attributes of that element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('label').each(function(idx) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'etiqueta' + idx);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the index of your each index loop and give it an `id` attribute:

```
$('label').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'etiqueta'+index);
});
```